# Null pointer exception at action bar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I am getting null pointer exception at action bar. I am using `getActionBar()`.Following are the errors..I am extending Activity

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.peoplecloud.guggu/com.peoplecloud.guggu.activity.LandingActivity_}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.peoplecloud.guggu.activity.LandingActivity.onCreate(LandingActivity.java:96)
            at com.peoplecloud.guggu.activity.LandingActivity_.onCreate(LandingActivity_.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

in following lines-

```
java:96 actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
```

Comment: are you using support Fragment ??

Comment: what minSdk are you using ?

Comment: @blackbelt minSdk 14

Comment: if you are using `SupportFragment`, try `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: @Panther I am not using support fragment..i am importing android.app.ActionBar and android.app.Fragment

Comment: is class `BaseGugguActivity`  extending `ActionBarActivity` and also what theme you are using ?

Comment: @Panther BaseGugguActivity extends Activity and i have added imports i am using in the question..

Comment: @user3753273 Not `Activity`, it should extend `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: well, `Ando` has summarised my whole thoughts as an answer :-/

Comment: @Panther BaseGugguActivity extends Activity so i am using getActionBar()...then where i am going wrong?

Comment: I mean, are you its the actionbar's fault?

Comment: @blackbelt I don't understand what u mean..check out  errors in question...its showing error at actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using **Activity** then use below code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

or you are using **ActionBarActivity** then [getSupportActionBar()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29)

**make sure that you have not used NoTitlebar Theme.**

**EDIT**

use

```
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
```

and  add in your layout xml file :

create seprate file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#E3493B"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" >
```

include it in your xml layout file

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Comment: then change it with ActionBarActivity  and getSupportActionBar() and just tell me u r using new V7 21 lib ? then has feature of Material design ??

Comment: @AndoMasahashi good question !. @user3753273 you should post some code of `BaseGugguActivity`

Comment: i a using appcompat-v7:21.0.+ and  compileSdkVersion 21

Comment: @Panther BaseGugguActivity posted

Comment: Guess you are encountering this http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html

Comment: Before that try this simple fix. First make sure you have not set `NoTitlebar Theme.` then on first line of `onCreate` write this `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);`

Comment: @Panther he required to change as i said its new way to implement for v7 21+

Comment: @AndoMasahashi changing with ActionBarActivity and getSupportActionBar() solved my issue..but can u please tell me why extending Activity and using getActionBar() doesn't worked..is it because i am using appcompat-v7:21.0.+ and compileSdkVersion 21?thanku for the help..

Answer (score 0):

two things:

if you are using support framework the use "getSupportActionBar()" to get the actionbar. But i see you are using an activity here. Your activity should extend ActionbarActivity to use actionbar eith er directly or using a fragmentactivity.

without that you wont get an actionbar in support packages..

Comment: I have added imports i am using in the question

Comment: BaseGugguActivity  extends what ?@user3753273

Comment: when i replace getActionBar() with getSupportActionBar() it shows error in red..what should i import for using getSupportActionBar()..thanks for help..i am fresher in android.

Comment: @AndoMasahashi BaseGugguActivity extends Activity

Answer (score 0):

The layout of the toolbar should be added to the activity layout

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```