# Actionbar wont change color for Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: java, android

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/cb_campaign"
            android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

styles.xml

```
 <resources>
        <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        </style>

        <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
            <item name="android:background">#FFCA09</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
}
```

[image: screenshot]
Edit:
Original question was: How to solve Android error: java.lang.IllegalStateException:You need to use a Theme.AppCompat

Changed AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

But action background color still won't change.

Comment: Used  `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: Where should I place it? @MD

Comment: instead of `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`

Comment: It turns to grey, its not using my hex code color

Comment: show me any screen shot

Comment: screenshot added @MD edited the code too and the question but the background color still doesn't change btw, API 19

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84589/discussion-between-m-d-and-woninana).

Answer (score 0):

Just switch on the Design view, then click on AppTheme button and just change theme.

that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn some material design from here [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the "android:" to use backwards-compatible attributes:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!--Backwards compatibility-->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
        <!--Backwards compatibility-->
        <item name="background">@color/red</item>
    </style>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: @woninana you sure you're actually using AppTheme in your manifest?

Comment: application  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Comment: @woninana should be `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Answer (score 0):

A reference to a style resource defining a default theme for all activities in the application. Individual activities can override the default by setting their own theme attributes. For more information, see the Styles and Themes developer guide.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/cb_campaign"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" in `<application>` tag u need to apply your theme.
one suggestion its better to go with material design 
[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636762/null-pointer-exception-at-action-bar/26636984#26636984)